# I can't install cordova plugins

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm trying to add this plugin https://github.com/MobileAppTracking/phonegap-plugin but when I run the command I see this error:

```
 Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'com.mobileapptracking.matplugin':TypeError: Uh oh!
Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:313:15)
    at module.exports.framework.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:106:31)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:70:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:567:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:322:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
TypeError: Uh oh!
Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:313:15)
    at module.exports.framework.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:106:31)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:70:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:567:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:322:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
```

My node version is v0.10.25
My npm version is 1.3.10
My cordova version is 3.6.3-0.2.13

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should update your Cordova version and cordova-android, remove the plugin and clean its installed dependencies, to have then a new clean install of the plugin

1. Update Cordova :

   ```
   sudo npm update -g cordova
   ```
2. Update android Platform

   ```
   cordova platform update android
   ```
3. In your case, it seems that you should remove the plugin

   ```
   cordova plugin remove com.mobileapptracking.matplugin
   ```
4. Remove manually Play Services dependency in your directories and
   in `android.json` file
5. Then reinstall the plugin

   ```
   cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileAppTracking/phonegap-plugin
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Cordova version and update your android platform or remove it totally and then add it once again.

Please Update Cordova :

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

please remove your android platform by using following command

```
cordova platform rm android
```

And then add platform using following command

```
cordova platform add android
```

Hopes this will help you !